# Convert to unixtime: same input, different output

Tags: java, apache-commons, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

Maybe this is a recurrent issue, but I need to explain my problem.

I must convert date+hour to Unix time format. I use Apache Commons Lang library, DateUtils class:

```
Date date = DateUtils.parseDate(strStartDateTime, new String[] { "ddMMyyyyHHmmss" });
Long dateLong = new Long(date.getTime());
```

Maybe Java Date class is old for this, but it seems to work fine.

But lately, I have detected that the same input, in right expected format, is returning different output in different executions.

I have been looking for a similar issue, and I have read that Java Date is old, joda-time library is recommended, etc.

It would be easy to convert with joda-time, but, why is this happening? Is reliable the code above? It's very likely I'm not taking something into account.

Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly is the output different?

Comment: Thank you @axtavt. For input date "15032012222117" (15 March), I have read 1331846477000 (right) and 1329897515000 (22 Feb, wrong) unix timestamps.

Comment: Thank you @Spaeth. The time zone could deviate 1 hour (my GMT is +1), but not 23 days.

Comment: This issue happens again, and a library trouble is discarded. The same input gave the same output with Commons Lang and Joda Time. If I know something more, I'll post here. Thanks.

Comment: Finally we found the error. There was a wrong attribute definition. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me, but finally I found the error. There was a wrong attribute definition.
It was my programming error; nothing related to time conversion. Thanks